# Encoding US-ASCII to UTF-8 add space character

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ascii, iconv

I'm trying to encode some log files from US-ASCII to UTF-8
I am using `iconv` for that.
When I encode utf-8 there is a space in the only first-line just one char.
I tried using `sed` but it makes the format US-ASCII in the server. When I convert it to UTF-8, there is a space again.
I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Comment: UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII so there should be no difference between the ASCII and UTF-8 files.  Please  [edit] the question to show the bytes in the source and result files, for example by copying the output of a tool like xxd.

Comment: `space in the only first line` - you mean the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)? `just one char` - are you sure you are converting to UTF-8 and not [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)?

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert the file? As snakecharmerb says, any file that is valid US-ASCII is also valid UTF-8, so no conversion is needed. If the file changes when converted (other than the addition of an extra "BOM" at the start) then it wasn't US-ASCII to start with.

Comment: @IMSoP The company to which we will send the log file want it as UTF-8. I will check out this UTF-8Bom thing. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @GSerg I'm sure because when i run the file -i command its output UTF-8. Thank you for your UTF-8Bom suggesiton i will check it

Comment: @snakecharmerb My friend asked me to solve it, I don't have the codes yet :(

Comment: Show the `iconv` line you're using for this. There is no conversion required from ASCII to UTF-8 (they are byte-for-byte identical), and `iconv` does not insert a BOM when writing UTF-8. When you say you use `file -i` and it outputs UTF-8, that doesn't make sense. `file -i` explicit does not identify the contents of regular files (that's what the `-i` means). `file` (without `-i`) would only indicate it's UTF-8 if it contains characters that *aren't* ASCII. Given your description, I don't believe you have an ASCII file in the first place. I suspect it's something else like Latin-1.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misconception about what character encodings are, and the relationship between ASCII and UTF-8. When we store text in a computer, we have to convert it into a binary sequence according to some code - we could choose something like "0001 means A, 0010 means B" and so on. To agree which code we're using, we give them names, like "ASCII" and "UTF-8".

If you look at a binary string, you can't tell what code its author was using; the best you can do is guess, by trying different codes and seeing which ones make sense. But some strings of bits will make sense in multiple codes - and, crucially for this question, they might mean **exactly the same thing** in multiple codes. For instance, two codes might both say that 0001 is an A, but one code says that 1110 means "?" and the other that it means "!". If all you have is a long line of A's, it will be written exactly the same way no matter which code you use.

In the case of UTF-8 and ASCII, this isn't coincidence; UTF-8 is **deliberately designed** so that anything written using ASCII will have **exactly the same** representation when written in UTF-8. The definition of UTF-8 basically begins with "if you can represent it using ASCII, do that; if you can't, follow these extra rules".

To use a different analogy, imagine the customer asked you to make sure the text was in British English, not American English - "colour" rather than "color", and so on. If the text you want to send is "It is raining today", there is nothing you need to change - the same exact string is both American English and British English at the same time.

If your text includes characters which *can't* be represented in ASCII, then it is not in ASCII. In that case, you need to know what encoding it is actually in - there are many encodings which, like UTF-8, are designed to be compatible with ASCII, so the majority of characters will be the same no matter which one you try. ISO 8859-1 and its cousin Windows-1252 are very common; ISO 8859-15 possibly more so in Europe; others in other parts of the world where they're useful for writing the local language.

The extra "space" you're seeing at the start of the file is probably the so-called "Byte Order Mark", a Unicode character deliberately defined as meaning nothing, but having a different representation in different encodings. It's there to give a hint to programs which want to guess the encoding used in a piece of text, but it is not mandatory, and the string was already valid UTF-8 before it was added.